# AttributeError - Namespace object has no attribute username

Tags: python, json, django, shell

Hi am new to python and tried to run below script and getting attribute error.

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
 import json
 import sys
 import argparse

  try:
    import requests
    except ImportError:
    print "Please install the python-requests module."
    sys.exit(-1)

   def get_json(location, devincuser, password):

    # Performs a GET using the passed URL location
    location += "?per_page=10000"
    r = requests.get(location, auth=(devincuser, password),verify=False)
    return r.json()

  def main():

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Satellite Errata                
   Reporter")

    # Arguments
    parser.add_argument("-u", "--devincuser", type=str.lower, help="Username  
   to access Satellite", action="store", default='devincuser')
    parser.add_argument("-p", "--password", type=str, help="Password to  
   access Satellite", action="store", default='password')
    parser.add_argument("-n", "--localhost", type=str.lower, help="Satellite     
   server (default: localhost)", default='localhost')
    parser.add_argument("-o", "--organization", type=str.lower, nargs="*",  
  help="Filter on this space-delimited list of organization(s)", default='')
    parser.add_argument("-e", "--environment", type=str.lower, nargs="*",  
  help="Filter on this space-delimited list of lifecycle environments",  
  default='')
    parser.add_argument("-c", "--collection", type=str.lower, nargs="*",  
   help="Filter on and group by this space-delimited list of host  
  collections", default='')
    parser.add_argument("-t", "--type", type=str.lower, nargs="*",  
  help="Filter on this space-delimeted list of errata types (bugfix,  
  enhancement, and/or security)", default='')
    parser.add_argument("-s", "--severity", type=str.lower, nargs="*",  
 help="Filter on this space-delimited list of severities (critical,  
 important, moderate, low)", default='')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    # Check username and password
    if not (args.username and args.password):
            print "No complete account information provided, exiting"
            exit (-1)

    # set up api url
    sat_api = "http://%s/172.17.12.129/api/v2/" % args.server
    katello_api = "http://%s/172.17.12.129/api/" % args.server

    # set up initial stuff
    prefix = "- "
    systems_fetched = False
    system_count = 0
    system_errata_count = 0

    # Loop through organizations and skip the ones we don't want
    orgs = get_json(sat_api + "organizations/", args.username,      
    args.password)
    for org in orgs['results']:
    if args.organization and org['name'].lower not in args.organization:
                    continue

  print "\nErrata for organization '%s':" % org['name']

  if args.collection:

  # Loop through the host collections, skip the one we don't want
    collections = get_json(sat_api + "organizations/" + str(org['id']) +  
 "/host_collections/", args.username, args.password)
    for collection in collections['results']:
   if collection['name'].lower() not in args.collection:
             continue
      print "\n" + prefix + "Errata for Host Collection '%s':" %  
collection['name']
            prefix = "  - "

  # Get the systems in this host collection
    systems = get_json(sat_api + "host_collections/" + str(collection['id']) 
+ "/systems/", args.username, args.password)
    systems_fetched = True

    else:
  # Get the systems in this Organization
  systems = get_json(sat_api + "organizations/" + str(org['id']) + 
"/systems/", args.username, args.password)
  systems_fetched = True

  if not systems_fetched:
  continue

  # loop through the systems fetched from the collection *or* the 
organization
  for system in systems['results']:
  system_errata = get_json(sat_api + "systems/" + system['uuid'] + 
"/errata", args.username, args.password)
  first = True

  # filter on lifecycle environment(s) (if specified)
  environment = system['environment']['name'].lower()
  if args.environment and environment not in args.environment:
  continue

  # Get all available Errata for System
  for system_erratum in system_errata['results']:

  # filter on type(s) (if specified)
   type = system_erratum['type'].lower()
   if args.type and type not in args.type:
    continue

  # filter on severity(s) (if specified)
   if type == "security" and "security" in args.type and args.severity:
   severity = system_erratum['title'].split(":")
[0].encode('ascii','ignore').lower()
   if severity not in args.severity:
   continue

  # We have an erratum, print system if this is the first
   if first:
   system_count += 1
   first = False
   print "\n" + prefix + system['name'], "("+system['environment'] 
['name']+")\n"

 # print the erratum id, type and title 
    print "  " + prefix + "%s: %s: %s" % 
(system_erratum['errata_id'],system_erratum['type'],system_erratum['title'])

  # Count the errata we find
    system_errata_count += 1

    if not first:
     print

 # print statistics
    if system_errata_count:
   print "\nNumber of errata to apply: %s" % system_errata_count
   print "Number of systems affected: %s" % system_count
   else:
    print "\nNo errata found for this selection"
    print
  if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and getting blow error
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "./pyth.py", line 136, in 
    main()
     File "./pyth.py", line 44, in main
    if not (args.username and args.password):
    AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'username'

Answer (score 2):

You haven't defined a `username` argument in your ArgumentParser. You've defined something called `devincuser`, did you mean to use that instead?

Comment: devincuser is authentication username

Comment: So where is the "username" argument coming from? You haven't defined it.

Comment: tTo run this script instructions given as - "satellite_errata_report (use satellite_errata_report -h or --help for usage) 
Please use a read-only account to access the Satellite API. These could be set as the default 
in the below parser arguments for username and password...                                    
below to these values. Alternatively, username and password can be specifed on the commandline"

Comment: Where are those instructions from? I don't know how many times I have to say it, your script **does not define a username argument**.